# SQL Express vs SQL Plus

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

I'm wondering what the difference is if any between SQL Express and SQL Plus.  I know SQL Plus is used with Oracle but not sure if SQL Plus is a modification of SQL Express or a totally different installation.

Thanks

Comment: I don't know of any "SQL Express" in the Oracle world. You may be thinking of either Oracle 10g Express Edition, which is a version of the database, or Oracle Application Express (APEX) which is a web application development tool built on Oracle (which, perhaps confusingly, also forms the basis of the database management tools provided by Oracle 10g Express).

Comment: I was just wondering what the differences were and if SQL Express install a SQL Plus Oracle interface or if it was all Oracle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sql Express is the express version of SQL Server. This can be used for development purpose. Sql Plus comes with Oracle. Its a command line tool to run PL/SQL scripts

Comment: I installed Oracle but it didn't automatically install SQL Plus.  Is there a way to install it as well when Oracle is installed?

Comment: you can install Sql plus from http://www.oracle.com/technology/tech/oci/instantclient/index.html

Comment: In looking at those installs I read that you have to have the SQL Plus version that matches Oracle.  I'm using Oracle v10.20221 but I only found a zip that has the sqlplus.exe not an installation that links it to Oracle.

Comment: Any SQL*Plus client equal to or greater than the database version you're connecting to should work fine.

Answer (score 3):

SQL Plus is the [command line interface to an Oracle instance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL*Plus), like SQL Server's [SQLCMD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx).

Both Oracle and SQL Server refer to their free versions as Express.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [SQLS*Plus](http://www.memfix.com) - this is a free SQL Server tool that acts as SQL*Plus for Oracle

Answer (score 0):

SQL Plus is a console-like interface that can be used with any Oracle database ("Express" or otherwise). You can use it with Oracle's Express Edition or regular Oracle.

MS SQL Express is analogous to Oracle Express Edition.

I am not sure if there is an analogue to SQL Plus from Microsoft.

Comment: Yes, there is `sqlcmd`. Please check 


  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh568447.aspx